# Steam blank login screen kubuntu

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, login, steam

I've installed steam from repo, then opened it, it did the usual update. After the update there was a blank login screen. Closed it, then reopened it but it is still blank.

As fa as I see, the login screen actually works, but there are no buttons, no text at all.

[image: Steam Blank login screen]

If I click somewhere at the bottom, the login user login screen opens but when you enter your username and password, there is another dialog, Steam Guard, which also has blank areas.

[image: Steam Guard blank screen]

Kubuntu 15.10 + backports ppa and I have nvidia gtx 850 m and nvidia propiriety drivers (352.63) installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04. I'm not sure if it will be same with you but, when Steam Guard pops up, just click next and enter your security code. I hope it works with you too.